# Can I duplicate server-side functionality without being able to use server-side tech?

Tags: javascript, html, ms-access, client-side

I have recently taken a position at a large corporation as a Web Developer for one of the company's divisions. For my first task I have been asked to create a web form that submits data to a database and then outputs the id# of that data to the user for reference later. Easy, right? Unfortunately not. Because this is a large company that has been around for a long time their systems are relatively antiquated and none of their servers support server-side technologies (PHP, ASP etc...) and since they are such a large company Corporate IT is pretty much a black hole and there is not any hope of actually getting such tech implemented.

SO! To my question... is there ANY way to do this without server-side? To me the answer is 'no' and I have spent the last week researching on sites like this and others without finding any miraculous work arounds. Really all I have at my disposal are things I can implement without involving IT, so things I can just upload to a web-server.

Also as a note: The web server it is on is supposedly an IBM Web Server (IHS) and the database I am supposed to be connecting to is a MS Access database and the company restricts us to using IE for any web access. As this form is on an internal company INTRAnet site IE is the only browser it will be accessed from.

I know this is a ridiculous situation but unfortunately that is what I am stuck with. Any ideas???

Comment: In short, you want to write directly to the database from a web page? What is serving the web page?

Comment: that doesn't make sense .... what Web Server is it?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add that. Its an IBM Web server (IHS) I believe.

Comment: In theory, since it is for an IE-only intranet, you might be able to put something together using shared network drives and ActiveX. That way, however, lies madness. Get a decent webserver in place. If IT won't cooperate, get a manager who cares about the project to push them or authorise a skunkworks project (in which you sneak a better server onto the system and blame the authorising manager if IT complain)

Comment: "IBM HTTP Server is based on the Apache HTTP Server, developed by the Apache Software Foundation"  How is MS Access accessible from your browser or desktop? Does everyone connect to an Access database file on a network share?

Comment: @Paul - The database is currently just accessable by our small team manually through a shared network drive.

Comment: @Quentin - This whole project is maddness without the server-side tech that was invented specifically to do this task, lol. Do you have anything off the top of your head you could link me to potentially look down this path?

Comment: @Spags ActiveX development is a nightmare. Tell them you need a server. Just ask for a linux box, refuse to do anything until then

Comment: @Raynos Trust me, I understand how much of a nightmare doing this stuff without server tech is going to be, lol. Maybe a hunger strike?

Comment: @Spags worse comes to worse, just quit.

Comment: @Raynos Ha ha ha ha, it has crossed my mind. I do feel like they misrepresented the position. They brought me on with tales of implementing a database solution for their work... they didn't mention it would be impossible to do. As mightmarish as it might prove to be does anoyone have any clue on how to do this thing with ActiveX?

Answer (score 1):

You *must* have something that takes form data and transforms it for insertion to the database.

There are no javascript libraries that will do this from the browser directly to database (security issues in traversing the network, cross domain issues etc...).

Something will be serving up the web pages - surely this can be the basis of the server side coding you need.

---

Seeing as you are using [IBM HTTP Server](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/httpservers/features/?S_CMP=rnav) (gleaned from comments on your question), there *are* server side scripting technologies available to you.

Comment: This is not an answer; it's a comment.

Comment: @Paul - you are trigger happy, eh?

Comment: Which technologies can I potentially assume would be available? I have been told that none are by my boss but perhaps that is not true (which would be amazing). Are there technologies that are default on this kind of web server?

Comment: CouchDB exposes the database over Ajax. You dont need a server.

Comment: Doesn't CouchDB require something to be installed on the server though?

Comment: @Spags couchdb can be hosted in the cloud :)

Comment: [Iris Couch](http://www.iriscouch.com) is highly nifty (and also easy to migrate from), should you go that route.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could create a [Web Database with Access Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402351.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

> Also as a note: The database I am supposed to be connecting to is a MS Access database and the company restricts us to using IE for any web access. As this form is on an internal company INTRAnet site IE is the only browser it will be accessed from.

That's easy. Use a dirty `ActiveX` hack to talk toe MS Access directly from the browser.

That's going to be a nightmare to code, but it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which version of Access you're using; [this page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-the-types-of-web-pages-access-creates-HP005269264.aspx) has information on how to set this up for Access 2003, click on "data access pages".

It's probably better in the long run if you don't solve this problem.  Management frustration with IT may help you effect change, or at least get you permission to set up a local web server so you can demonstrate what's possible with the right support.

Comment: I have thought about that. And it may be the way that I go. If I find some ugly hacked together solution now then I'm stuck in that role forever. If I just amke it clear it can't be done maybe I can save us all from the dark ages... Also I don't know exactly what version of Access it is because honestly they have not gotten me the software to access the Access database myself yet. I have 2007 version of other Office products though so I would guess that its that.

Comment: How many people will be using this thing? If the answer is "more than six", then Access is absolutely the wrong answer. Far, far more trouble than it's worth.